# argument not recognized for-loop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new pretty new when it comes to creating scripts in linux (I also don't really know on which terms to use like bash/shell), but I have the following command in a script which I want to execute with some arugments

**write_loop.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
for i in {1..$1}; do printf "file '%s'\n" $2 >> list.txt; done
```

I'm trying to execute it like this in the terminal with 2 arguments: the amount of times to loop (150) and the filename to loop ("loop.mp4")

```
./write_loop.sh 150 loop.mp4
```

The arguments are passed to the script just fine, but for some reason the for-loop is not working. When I manually change `$1` to `150` in *write_loop.sh* it does work, so I'm not sure what the issue is (maybe the argument is of a different type?). Any bit of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables can't be used in range expansion `{INT..INT}`, so fallback to that is to use `seq` as show in [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7799/85039). Alternatively, use C-like for loop since you're using `bash` anyway:

```
#!/bin/bash           
echo $1
echo $2
echo {1..$1}
for((i=1;i<=$1;i++)); do 
   printf "'%s'\n" "$2"
done
```

Or POSIX-ly:

```
#!/bin/bash           
echo $1
echo $2
i=1
while [ $i -le $1  ]; do 
   printf "'%s'\n" "$2"
   i=$((i+1))
done
```

Note I changed `printf` part for testing purposes. Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Love that you gave multiple options on how to do it. I used the `C-like` for loop because I'm the most comfortable with that syntax (for now).